# how to update linux kernel on ubuntu with dpkg errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I tried to update the Linux kernel to 6.1.38 on Ubuntu 22.04. After downloading the kernel file from the Ubuntu Kernel website and installing it, there appeared to be dependency problems.

```
dpkg -i linux-headers-6.1.38-060138-generic-64k_6.1.38-060138.202307070815_arm64.deb
```

And the output is

```
(Reading database ... 102570 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-6.1.38-060138-generic-64k_6.1.38-060138.202307070815_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.1.38-060138-generic-64k (6.1.38-060138.202307070815) over (6.1.38-060138.202307070815) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-6.1.38-060138-generic-64k:
 linux-headers-6.1.38-060138-generic-64k depends on linux-headers-6.1.38-060138; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.1.38-060138 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.1.38-060138-generic-64k (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.1.38-060138-generic-64k
```

I have tried to use the command below, but it didn't work.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install linux-headers-6.1.38-060138
```

Solutions below didn't work either.

```
apt-get install linux-headers-6.1.38-060138
apt -f install
```

Comment: What was the result of the `apt-get install` command?

Answer (score 0):

use the following command:

```
apt install linux-headers-6.1.38-060138
apt -f install
```